# Setting the state within a request module

Tags: reactjs, api, rest, request, node-modules

I am making a small react.js application and plan on calling two different API's. The first API is giving me specific coordinates, which I will then dynamically use within my second API call. My plan was to save the coordinates by saving them to state within the request module but keep getting "this.setState is not a function". Reading a little bit more into it, I believe I need to make my request a fat arrow function but havent been able to successfully do it. Any ideas on how to setState within the request module and how to dynamically update the second API call? Appreciate all the help!

````
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            lat: '',
            long: '',
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let request = require('request');

        let options1 = {
            method: 'GET',
            json: true,
            url: url1,
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
            },
        };
        request(options1, function (error1, response1, body1) {
            if (error1) throw new Error(error1);
            this.setState({ lat: response1, long: response1 });
        });

        let options = {
            method: 'GET',
            json: true,
            url: url,
            qs: { lat:`${this.state.lat}` , lng: `${this.state.long}`, dt: '2018-01-24T10:50:52.283Z' },
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'x-access-token': `${process.env.REACT_APP_UV_API_KEY}`,
            },
        };
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) throw new Error(error);
            console.log(response.body.result.uv);
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <header>
                    <Home />
                </header>
            </div>
        );
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

I would want to point out that this.setState comes at a cost of re-render and from what I see inside the render method, you don't really rely on lat, long for rendering. So, it's preferred to use it as a constant variable rather than a state variable.

If you want to stick to using them as state variables, there are a bunch of ways to do it. The arrow function would go like this:

```
request(options1, (error1, response1, body1) => {
      if (error1) throw new Error(error1);
      this.setState({ lat: response1, long: response1 });
    });
```

`this` needs to have the right scope to work and arrow functions solve that. You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

You can even assign `this` to another variable and use it inside request

```
    const self = this;
    request(options1, function(error1, response1, body1) {
      if (error1) throw new Error(error1);
      self.setState({ lat: response1, long: response1 });
    });
```

An arrow function is a preferred approach.